# Javascript - verify if xpath exists or not: $x vs document.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, xpath, document.evaluate

I need to verify if a specific element on a web page exists. I just need a true/false, null/string, 0/1 or similar in response. When I google this, all solutions I find use `document.evaluate` (and that is also what ChatGPT suggests).

Why is `document.evaluate` preferred to `$x` for this purpose?

$x seems much more straightforward.

The context is scripting a browser.

Answer (score 0):

### `$x()` is a developer tool utility

`$x` is a **non-standard tool, only available in the browser developer tools**. It does not exist when executing a script.

```js
const result = $x("//p");

for (const next of result)
  console.log(`tag: ${next.tagName} content: ${next.textContent}`);
}
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<div>Not a paragraph tag</div>
```

```js
const result = document.evaluate("//p", document);
let next;
while (next = result.iterateNext()) {
  console.log(`tag: ${next.tagName} content: ${next.textContent}`);
}
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
<div>Not a paragraph tag</div>
```

### The implementation of `$x()` is not consistent between browser dev tools

It is implemented in both Chrome, and Firefox, however even then it works differently in both places. So, even if you want to somehow inject code that runs in the browser console but you target multple browsers, you might get inconsistent results based on how you invoke `$x()`.

#### [In Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#xpath-function):

> $x(path [, startNode])
>
> $x(path) returns an array of DOM elements that match the given XPath expression.
>
> [...]
>
> Similar to the other selector functions, `$x(path)` has an optional second parameter, `startNode`, that specifies an element or Node from which to search for elements.

#### [In Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/helpers/index.html):

> $x(xpath, element, resultType)
>
> Evaluates the XPath `xpath` expression in the context of `element` and returns an array of matching nodes. If unspecified, `element` defaults to `document`. The resultType parameter specifies the type of result to return; it can be an XPathResult constant, or a corresponding string: `"number"`, `"string"`, `"bool"`, `"node"`, or `"nodes"`; if not provided, `ANY_TYPE` is used.